# How to return success sending an email laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to give a mail success response in laravel.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/contatti/','ItemController@contatti');
Route::post('/contatti/mail','ItemController@mail');
```

Here is my method

```
public function mail()
        {

$data = Input::all();
 $rules = array(
'nome' => 'required',
'email' => 'required',
 );
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);    
if($validator->fails()) return Redirect::to('contatti')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();                       
$emailcontent = array (
 'nome' => $data['nome'],
 'email' => $data['email'],
 );

 Mail::send('emails.contactmail', $emailcontent, function($message){

 $message->to('xxxx @mail.com','')->subject('Contatti');

});
$success='ok';  
return Redirect::back()->with('success',$success);
}
```

HTML

```
@if(isset($success))
<div>
    Email Inviata con successo!
</div>
@endif
```

I can't do that because I am using a route method post?
I need to use something like :

Session::flash('success', 'Successfully sent');
to set this? And then get the session in the Contact page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects):

> Note: Since the **with** method flashes data to the session, you may
>   retrieve the data using the typical **Session::get** method.

So, your HTML template should be:

```
@if(Session::get('success'))
<div>
    Email Inviata con successo!
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: If i don't use isset variable success need to exist always in my view. 
I usually don't need to session:get with method.
I just use ->with ('success',$success) and i get variable like this in the view.
The problem here is that it seems that i can't give a value to variable success

Comment: If you use `with` in a redirection, you **must** use `Session`. If you don't want to use `Session`, then do not use `with`.

Comment: I understand now. I didn't know redirect worked diffferent, thank you